# Unable to compile project in android studio Gradle: invalid symbol: 'switch'

Tags: android, debugging, uiswitch

I am using Android studio to compile the project. Project min SDK is 14 and target is 17.

I am using this code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <Switch
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Switch"
            android:id="@+id/switch" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is compilation error which is shown in image

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can workarround this error if u change the ID of your switch to something else than "@+id/switch". For example:

```
 <Switch
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Switch"
            android:id="@+id/Switch"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Switch"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Switch"/>
```

Would be a valid switch.

source: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55720